# How to project 3D plots on a 2D coordinate system without losing the metric scale?

Tags: metric-spaces, graphing-functions, transformation, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry

I've been collection data of a river bank last week and I need to plot the cross sections of the data.

The issue is, that the data taken consists of 3 coordinates: easting, northing and elevation. Here is an example data set:

```
Easting     Northing    Elevation
408797.964  5620093.075 738.943
408797.892  5620092.864 738.718
408797.564  5620092.021 738.567
408797.118  5620090.892 738.497
408796.672  5620089.418 738.570
408796.612  5620089.275 738.776
408796.400  5620088.506 739.217
```

Which looks plotted like that (plotted with R):

[image: 2D plot]

What I did so far is [plotting the 3D points to a 2D plane](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/routines/3d_to_2d.htm) by dividing easting and northing.

$$x = \frac{easting}{northing} \cdot n + c$$

with $x$ being the new x-value (width of the river), $n$ being an zoom factor and $c$ the center (of the channel). So far so good.

But the zoom factor now is an issue for me as I have to **maintain the scale of both axes in meter**. I achieved to plot this image above using a zoom factor of $20,000,000$. But this is only an approximation of the real zoom factor.

Now my question is, **how to determin a correct zoom factor** to maintain the scale of both the x- and the y-axis to be $1$ meter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is quite simple, I finally figured out.

You just have to calculate the ratio of the distance of two known points both with the real coordinates and the projected coordinates along the scaled zoom-axis (here: $x$).

Let's say there is point $P(408796.400;5620088.506)$ at the left side of the river and point $Q(408797.964;5620093.075)$ on the right side. Projecting the easting and northing into a new $x$-axis like described in the question above results new $x$-values for the points. The elevation can be ignored.

$$q = \frac{Q_{easting}}{Q_{northing}} = \frac{408796.400}{5620088.506} = 0.07273842743998950112$$
$$p = \frac{P_{easting}}{P_{northing}} = \frac{408797.964}{5620093.075} = 0.07273864659261003431$$

Now we just calculate the distance of $|\overline{QP}|$ and $|\overline{qp}|$:

$$ |\overline{QP}| = \sqrt{(P_x - Q_x)^2 + (P_y - Q_y)^2} =  4.82927085593674275535 $$
$$ |\overline{qp}| = | p - q | = 2.1915262053319 \cdot 10^{-7}$$

The wanted zoom factor is the ratio of the distances:

$$ n = \frac{|\overline{QP}|}{|\overline{qp}|} = 22036108.1888380354757 $$

The guessed $20kk$ wasn't that bad at all.